# db transaction (commit and rollback) in datastage

Tags: sql-server, transactions, commit, rollback, datastage

Is there a way to implement transaction in job datastage, a way to rollback all upsert when i.e. my job aborts?
If not, is there a way or standard practice, a workaround, to simulate commit/rollback sistem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good practice, in DW ETL process, you need to design you job as re-entrance able
rather than transaction,  transaction is expensive, you just need to fix the issue and restart the job, in most cases ,you can't get issues fixed without human interfere,